# Longtable placed / filled over entire page

Tags: longtable, tabularx

I have a longtable in Overleaf, however I need to add 2 more columns, therefore I would like my longtable to fill the entire page. I just cannot find a way to alter my table. Any ideas?

Current picture of table
[image]

Code of table

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.22\textwidth}|p{0.42\textwidth}|p{0.42\textwidth}|p{0.42\textwidth}|p{0.42\textwidth}}
\caption{xxxxxxxxxx} \label{xxxxxx} \\

\hline \rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{xxxxx}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{xxxxx}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{xxxxxx}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{(xxxxx}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{xxxxxx}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{xxxx}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{xxxx}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{xxxxx}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{(xxxx}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{xxxx}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Direct}}} & Method & x & 
Advantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
Disadvantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
& x   \\ 
 & Method & x & 
 Advantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
Disadvantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
& x \\ 
 & Method & x & 
 Advantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
Disadvantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
& x\\ 
 & Method & x & 
 Advantages: \par
(1) Tx \par
(2) x \par
Disadvantages: \par
(1) x  \par
(2) x \par \\
 & Method & x & 
  Advantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
Disadvantages: \par
(1) x \par
(2) xxx \par
& x  \\
 & Method & x & 
 Advantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
Disadvantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
& x  \\
\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Indirect}}} & Method & x & 
Advantages: \par
    (1) x \par 
    (2) xx \par
Disadvantages: \par 
    (1) x \par
    (2) x \par
    (3) x. \par 
& x  \\
% & x & x & 
%  Advantages: \par
% (1) xxx \par
% % (2) xxx \par
% Disadvantages: \par
% (1) xxx \par
% (2) xxx \par
% x \\ \hline
 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Independent}}}  & Method & x & 
Advantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
Disadvantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
& x \\
 & Method & x & 
 Advantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
Disadvantages: \par
(1) xxx \par
(2) xxx \par
& x  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

PACKAGES

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{multirow} %table
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Example after using code by Zarko
**Edit:** I don't see any reason to repeat here result of compiling of MWEs given in my answer. Especially, if it not consider final version of answer.

So I took a liberty and delete this image (which is inaccurate and misleading), since any one can see results in my answer.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please provide a *Minimal* working example: a compilable piece of code that contains just enough to show your problem. There are a lot of packages here that are probably irrelevant for the problem at hand.

Comment: @Miyase Thank you for the comment! I reduced the list of packages to just the relevant ones.

Comment: Thanks, but your code is still incomplete (no `\begin{document}`?) and it's fragmented into several parts. Keep it in one piece so that people can copy-paste it easily.

Comment: you are forcing the columns to be wider than needed with`p{0.22\textwidth}` alsonever use `center` with `longtable`

Comment: I used a multi-paged longtable Source: https://texblog.org/2011/05/15/multi-page-tables-using-longtable/   Which may be the reason why it seems disconnected. Moreover, there is no \begin{document}. This is for my thesis, and I used a template which has split up the different chapters into their own file. e.g., chapter 1 introduction, chapter 2 literature review. I believe that \begin{document}  is placed in the <main> folder which also stores the packages and such @DavidCarlisle

Comment: |p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.22\textwidth}|p{0.42\textwidth}|p{0.42\textwidth}|p{0.42\textwidth}|p{0.42\textwidth}  -->Should I change it to e.g., |c||c||c||c| ? @DavidCarlisle. It's just that I don't want the columns to be to big, because columns 3,4, and 5 will have a lot of text

Comment: @majapo the multi-file structure of your real document is not of interest here,  The point of posting example code is for people to see the issue and test answers, and that requires a document not disconnected fragments. You can make a small but complete document using `article`class and `longtable`package that shows the problem you are asking about.

Comment: clearly you can not have 4 columns that are .42\textwidth wide and have the total be less than `\textwidth` and so fit on the page. That is simple arithmetic, nothing particularly about `longtable`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `xltabular`, a combination of `tabularx` and `longtable` packages, instead of `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[arpaper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \setlength\LTcapwidth\linewidth
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\textbf{Independent}}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| c | *{6}{R|}}
\caption[blabla]{\lipsum*[66]}
\label{tab:primer}                              \\  
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\thead{Category}
    &   \thead{Tehnique}
        &   \thead{Description}
            &   \thead{Dis)advantages}
                &   \thead{Example}              
                    &   \thead{xxxxx}
                        &   \thead{xxxxxx}      \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{\lipsum*[66] (Cont.)}                \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\thead{xxxxx}
    &   \thead{xxxxx}
        &   \thead{xxxxxx}
            &   \thead{xxxxx}
                &   \thead{xxxxxx}
                    &   \thead{xxxxx}
                        &   \thead{xxxxxx}      \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline 
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\small\emph{Continued on next page}} \\ 
    \endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
\multirow{3}{*}[3ex]{\rothead{Direct}}
    & Method 
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx 
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx         \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}[3ex]{\rothead{Indirect}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx 
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx         \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}[1ex]{\rothead{Independent}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx  
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx             \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}[3ex]{\rothead{Indirect}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx  
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx             \\
\multirow{6}{*}[2ex]{\rothead{Direct}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx         \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}[3ex]{\rothead{Indirect}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx         \\
\end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Regarding your comment(s): at width of columns you are restricted with text width. So you cannot define any width of column. Some reasonable measure which you can take are:

- use smaller font, for example `\small` or `\footnotesize` )I don't recommend smaller)
- change ratio between column width
- for text in the first column header use use abbreviation, for example `C.`

```
\documentclass[arpaper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \setlength\LTcapwidth\linewidth
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\textbf{Independent}}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|      >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C |
                                *{2}{>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}R|}
                                *{4}{>{\hsize=1.10\hsize}R|}}
\caption[blabla]{\lipsum*[66]}
\label{tab:primer}                              \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\thead{C.}
    &   \thead{Tehnique}
        &   \thead{Description}
            &   \thead{Dis)advantages}
                &   \thead{Example}
                    &   \thead{xxxxx}
                        &   \thead{xxxxxx}      \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{\lipsum*[66] (Cont.)}                \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\thead{xxxxx}
    &   \thead{xxxxx}
        &   \thead{xxxxxx}
            &   \thead{xxxxx}
                &   \thead{xxxxxx}
                    &   \thead{xxxxx}
                        &   \thead{xxxxxx}      \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\small\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
\multirow{11}{*}{\rothead{Direct}}
    & \lipsum[1][1-1]
        & \lipsum[1][1-2]
            &   \lipsum[1][1-3]
                &   \lipsum[1][1-4]Method
                    &   \lipsum[66]
                        &   \lipsum[66]     \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}[4ex]{\rothead{Indirect}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx         \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}[1ex]{\rothead{Independent}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx             \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}[3ex]{\rothead{Indirect}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx             \\
    \hline
\multirow{6}{*}[2ex]{\rothead{Direct}}
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx         \\
\end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you able to use (recent version of) tabularray package, than the table code is far simpler and not require manual tweaking of \multirow cells since in your table are not needed. For example:

```
\documentclass[arpaper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {\lipsum*[66]},
  entry = {blabla},
  label = {tab:primer}           
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {Q[c,m] 
                            *{2}{X[0.70, l,h]}
                            *{4}{X[1.15, l,h]}
                            },
                  colsep = 3pt,
                 cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=\rotcell[cc]},
                  row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries, c, bg=lightgray},
                 rowhead = 1,
                 vspan=even}
%%%% COLUMNS HEADERS
Cat.
    &   Tehnique 
        &   Description 
            &   advantages 
                &   Example 
                    &   xxxxx 
                        &   xxxxxx              \\
%%%% BODY 
Direct
    & \lipsum[1][1-1]
        & \lipsum[1][1-2]
            &   \lipsum[1][1-3]
                &   \lipsum[1][1-4]
                    &   \lipsum[66]
                        &   \lipsum[66]     \\
Indirect
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx         \\
Independent
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx             \\
Indirect
    & Method
        & x &   Advantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx \par
                Disadvantages: \par
                (1) xxx \par
                (2) xxx
                & Method
                    & x &   Advantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx \par
                            Disadvantages: \par
                            (1) xxx \par
                            (2) xxx             \\
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Do you know by any change if it is possible to (1) change the width of the columns and/or (2) fill the page more (enlarge the table to the right and left of the page)?

Comment: @majapo, width of `X` columns is determined by LaTeX so, that table has prescribed width. It can be increased on two ways: (i) by reducing width non `X` columns, or (ii) locally enlarge `\textheight` of page. Also may be a possibility to change widths ratios between columns but for this suggestion you need to provide more realistic content of table.

Comment: as you can see I have added a picture as an example. The issue is that columns 4 - 7 require more space, because the text falls off the page. Therefore, I think that I should (1) change the width of the first 3 columns and/or fill the table over the entire page (on the left and right). P.S. I took your code as an example!

Comment: what is in the first column? Why is its column header empty? You can also use smaller font size ..

Comment: That is the category (direct, indirect or independent), excellent observation - I forgot to include the column header. I am afraid that a smaller font size will make it hard to read, especially once I print it out (I must do this for my thesis).

Comment: @majapo,  see addendum to answer.

Comment: @majapo, any news? Does answer solve your problem. If yes, I will be nice to accept them (by clicking an check mark at top left side of answer (as I see, you not accept any of received answer. Does any of the fulfill your expectation?